# Docker + SQL Server Cannot assign requested address

Tags: python, sql-server, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker image using the `compose.yml` file as below

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  flask:
    build: 
      context: consumelogs/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.web
    env_file:
      - ./consumelogs/.env
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  worker:
    build: 
        context: consumelogs/
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.worker
    env_file:
      - ./consumelogs/.env
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

And my SQL Server's (which is a Docker image) command is

```
docker run -d --name sql_server -e ‘ACCEPT_EULA=Y’ -e ‘SA_PASSWORD=123456’ --net slackbot-net -p 1433:1433 mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

where the default userName = `sa` and my bridge network = `slackbot-net`. My python app docker is started using the command

```
docker-compose up --build --force-recreate
```

I know that if I use `localhost` as ServerName, it points to docker itself, but I've tried my machine's IP address, `0.0.0.0`, `127.0.0.1` and even the IP address from the query

```
SELECT  
   CONNECTIONPROPERTY('net_transport') AS net_transport,
   CONNECTIONPROPERTY('protocol_type') AS protocol_type,
   CONNECTIONPROPERTY('auth_scheme') AS auth_scheme,
   CONNECTIONPROPERTY('local_net_address') AS local_net_address,
   CONNECTIONPROPERTY('local_tcp_port') AS local_tcp_port,
   CONNECTIONPROPERTY('client_net_address') AS client_net_address
```

and I still get **Cannot assign requested address**. Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Azure Data Studio is able to connect to the SQL Server from docker using `localhost` and username/password combo, just fine and so does my python tool using `pytds`, but just not from within docker.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you try the port?  So like localhost:1433?

Comment: When you use the `docker run` command are you really surrounding your environment variables with backticks like that? In bash-like shells `\`ACCEPT_EULA=Y\`` is executing the command `ACCEPT_EULA=Y`, which is setting the variable inside its own little environment space, and outputting the stdout stream to the command line - which will be nothing. You might have more success using apostrophes, e.g.: `docker run -d --name sql_server -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=StrongPassw0rd' --net slackbot-net -p 1433:1433 mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest`

Comment: As to your question, containers needing to access services running outside their composition (i.e.: on the Docker host itself, or exposed by other containers) would normally reference `host.docker.internal`. This works on Docker Desktop but probably won't work in any cloud-based Docker environments.

Comment: @gmalenko I tried localhost:1433, no luck.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning The backticks or apostrophes aren't an issue, since the Sql Server Docker is running fine. My issue is not being able to connect from another Docker, which is running my python app to the Sql Server Docker

Comment: You mention that you know that `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` point to the Docker container itself, so have you tried `host.docker.internal` yet?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes tried `host.docker.internal` too, didn't work

Comment: Are these all running on the same host computer? i.e.: you're not trying to communicate between Docker containers on physically seperate Docker hosts? Or Docker containers nested inside Hyper-V/VirtualBox/etc virtual machines?

Comment: Yes, same machine. Its all running on my mac laptop. No nesting nor other machines/vm's involved